# How can I convert Foreach loop with Linq expression OR AsEnumerable in C#.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq, linq-to-objects

How can I do below code with Linq expression in C#.net?

Currently, I am doing this with a foreach loop of DataTable.

I want to do it with LINQ or AsEnumerable() function.

**Current C# code**:

```
protected String GetRecommendMasterSquence() 
{
    ArrayList strItems = new ArrayList();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(dr["isSelected"])) {
            strItems.Add(Convert.ToString(dr["RecommendID"]));
        }
    }
    return string.Join(",", (string[]) strItems.ToArray(Type.GetType("System.String")));

}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `ArrayList` anymore. It belongs old days when C# doesn't have _Generics_. Use `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combination of `string.Join` and `.ToArray()` on Enumerable.

```
string str = string.Join(",", dt.AsEnumerable()
                                .Where(r => r.Field<bool>("isSelected"))
                                .Select(c=>c.Field<string>("RecommendID"))
                                .ToArray());
```

Comment: You don't need an array to use `String.Join` (with at least .NET 4). You have also forgotten to add the `Where`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `table.AsEnumerable` + `Enumerable.Where`:

```
var selectedRecommendIDs = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<bool>("isSelected"))
    .Select(r => r.Field<int>("RecommendID"));
string result = string.Join(",", selectedRecommendIDs);
```

Note that i've presumed that `isSelected` is a `bool` column and that `RecommendID` is an `int` column. Change it accordingly if that's not true. It should give you an idea anyway. It's better to use the `DataRow.Field` extension method anyway since it is strongly typed and support nullable types.

Comment: @Tim_Schmelter Good answer with description.. great

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = dt.Rows
       .Where(x => !Convert.ToBoolean(x["isSelected"]))
       .Select(x => Convert.ToString(x["RecommendID"]))

return string.Join(",", ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var recommendIds = 
            from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where myRow.Field<bool>("isSelected") == true
            select myRow.Field<string>("RecommendID");

        return string.Join(",", recommendIds.ToArray());
```